I'm not able to install copula package on my Mac
I'm attempting to install the copula package along with its dependencies in R version 4.0.2 on MacOS, but I'm encountering multiple errors related to the compilation of dependencies. Here is what I've tried:
install.packages("copula")
I chose to install from sources when prompted. However, the process fails with errors during the compilation of Matrix, gsl, mvtnorm, and pcaPP. The key issues include:
For Matrix, the error is related to linking with -lgfortran (not found).
For gsl, the configuration fails because gsl-config is not found.
For mvtnorm, the error is related to missing gfortran.
pcaPP and ultimately copula fail due to these unmet dependencies.
Here are excerpts from the error logs:
Matrix and gsl related errors:
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
configure: error: gsl-config not found, is GSL installed?

mvtnorm related error:
gfortran: No such file or directory
make: *** [mvt.o] Error 1

Suspect the issues might be related to the absence of certain compilers or paths not being properly configured. How can I resolve these installation issues to successfully install the copula package and its dependencies on MacOS?
Here is what I've tried:
install.packages("copula")

I chose to install from sources when prompted. However, the process fails with errors during the compilation of Matrix, gsl, mvtnorm, and pcaPP. The key issues include:
For Matrix, the error is related to linking with -lgfortran (not found).
For gsl, the configuration fails because gsl-config is not found.
For mvtnorm, the error is related to missing gfortran.
pcaPP and ultimately copula fail due to these unmet dependencies.
Here are excerpts from the error logs:

Does anyone help me?

Your diagnosis is basically correct. You can install gfortran from here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ — For other packages (such as ‘gsl’) you’ll need to follow the installation instructions for those specific packages. Or you simply don’t install from source.

@KonradRudolph thank you for your response, I appreciate it alot! However, problem is that I'm not very familiar with R, haven't used it in years actually.
Is there another quick fix I can apply? Like deleting everything or something?

The “quick fix” would be to rerun the package installation and, when prompted, don’t choose “install from source”. This should work.
